# get RDF model from DBpedia which starts with a specific resource

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

please i need your help, i want to get an RDF graph graph from dbpedia which starts with a specific resource and contain objects and objects of thhis objects etc
my code is as the following, it dosent work

```
     package Sparql;

     import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
     import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
     import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
     import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
     import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;

     /**
     *
     * @author Nada
     */
     public class Sparql
      {

     public Sparql()
       {
         }

     public static String querySparql()
       {
     String query=                
            "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"+
            "PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
            "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"+
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"+
            "prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
            "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+
            "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>"+
            "PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"+
            "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
            "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>"+
            "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>";


            query+= "CONSTRUCT {"+
            "?s ?p ?o }"+
            "WHERE {"+
            " \"http://dbpedia.org/resource/FIFA\" ?p ?o . ?o ?pp ?oo"+
            "}"
            ;



               return query;
                 }

               public Model executeSparqlQuery()
                 {
                   Query query = QueryFactory.create(querySparql());
                  QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(                  "http: //dbpedia.org/sparql", query );
                Model model = exec.execConstruct();
                return model;
               }


          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this maybe a duplicate of similar question answered recently which I cannot locate.

Many ways to achieve this but keeping it similar to your query -

```
CONSTRUCT {
 ?s ?p ?o .
 ?o ?pp ?oo .
} 
WHERE {
 ?s ?p ?o .
 ?o ?pp ?oo .
 FILTER ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/FIFA> )
}
```

The main problem I can see in your query is that you have made 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/FIFA' a literal not a URI.

Also you have specified `?o ?pp ?oo .` in your `WHERE` clause but not the `CONSTRUCT`. I've added `?o ?pp ?oo .` to the `CONSTRUCT` clause.